# Should I use multiple mysql database table to store php array data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Food Website where chef can add their product details from a form.

**Form field name is bellow :**

1. name
2. description
3. price
4. list of menu ( user can add more )
   a. menu name
   b. menu description
      **( Add more + )**
5. Data and time ( User can add more)
      **( Add more + )**

According to this form I am using following table structure to mysql database :

**Table name : products**

```
pid   name      des    price    menuname         menudes         datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

1     chicken   des    3        serialize data   serialize data  serialize data
2     chicken2  des    4        serialize data   serialize data  serialize data
3     chicken3  des    5        serialize data   serialize data  serialize data
4     chicken4  des    6        serialize data   serialize data  serialize data
```

So, you see that `list of menu` and `data and time` fields can be 3, 4, or more. So that, I am using php array to get value from these 2 fields and serialize it and then saving it to database.

**My Question is :**

1) Should I use another 2 table for that `list of menu` and `data and time` field ? If so, why ?
2) Or, I should use php serialize data to store these 2 fields value like currently what I am doing ?
3) If I used another 2 table to store these 2 fields data How can I update value ?

For example : Below table, You see that `pid` 1 has 2 date time value. So to update any one value out of 2, Should I need to delete these 2 date time and save the date time again ?

**date table :**

```
id    pid    dat3_time
----------------------
1     1      1201245772    
2     1      1201245772
3     2      1201245772
4     2      1201245772
5     3      1201245772
```

Comment: if you store menu & date-time in other table, it help you at the time search & also normalized table always help the processing speed. But whether you need it or not, will depends on your requirement.whether there is any option to search menu name, then 2nd table is effective. to save data in your date table will depend on your business logic

Comment: Thanks @DipanwitaKundu but How can I update value if I use another 2 table ? To update value, should I need to delete existing all value of specific ID and save all data again ?

Comment: Let me know why date table store duplicate date3_time....

Comment: In my form User can I add multiple date and time. So If I use another table for date and time there will multiple date and time for 1 PID, right ?

Comment: then date table should contain user id also, so at the time of updataion, you will update those date where user_id=<your user_id> and product_id=<your_product_id>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Yes you should, for scalability reason and to keep you structure consistent you should store all products related to a menu

2.- It is a posibility, but you won't be able to search by products and you will have trouble updating or removing elements asociated with the menu.

3.- That's the basics of SQL, I suggest you to read about joins and updates.
One simple and not working example would be.

```html
UPDATE products_time SET available_time = $newtime 
JOIN products ON products.id = products_time.productId
WHERE product.id = $productId
```

Comment: I understand your update query but you see that I have same 2 pid in date time table. Then how can I update it ? I think I have to update it based on table id. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes you will, but that won't be a problem, because when displaying the results you will select the ID of the joined table so it will already be available to you when you SELECT the data and display it

Comment: SELECT products_time.* FROM products_time
JOIN products ON products.id = products_time.product.id